# How can I log web service requests between my IIS web application and a 3rd party web service?

Tags: logging, network-monitoring

My web application (running in local IIS) makes a web service call to a 3rd party service. I'm trying to see the request to verify that it is formatted correctly.

I'm trying to do this with Fiddler, but I think it might not be the tool for this job. Fiddler shows me all the traffic originating from my browser to the (local) web server, but it does not show me any activity from aspnet_wp or inetinfo processes.

Am I using the wrong tool, or am I not using it correctly?

How can I see a log of the requests my web application is making?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

if you want to use fiddler you'll have to tell [your asp[x] code] to use fiddler as a proxy - localhost:8888. alternatively you can just use regular network sniffer like [wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/).